# altium input/output pin error

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator

I have a problem (stm32f407vgt6) with altium input output pin error. I will use 3.3 volt in my mcu that's why I added 5-3.3 voltage regulator in the circuit but I ve taken this error. Details

VCC0 contains Output Pin and Power Pin objects (Pin U1-5,Pin MCU-6,Pin MCU-11,Pin MCU-19,Pin MCU-28,Pin MCU-50,Pin MCU-75,Pin MCU-100)

output of voltage regulator is naturally 3.3 V but altium does not give a chance to use this volt as an input of mcu. what is the solution?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually I set the pin type as passive on the device consuming power, which eliminates the error.

(as an aside, you seem to have some kind of overlap or misalignment on the power pin node resulting in that dot).

Comment: If I use pin type as a passive, is there any problem power routes in  PCB?

Comment: The routing is up to you, the pin type is for checking that outputs are not connected to outputs and similar errors (is there a driving source?- well it won't find it if you send the signal to a connector and don't change the connector pin type, which is umm inelegant). It's often just a nuisance, but sometimes it can find an error.

Comment: @MevlüdeTigre: the pin type is just information for the schematic Electrical Rule Check function - ERC errors are to inform you of possible wiring errors on the schematic.  They will not prevent parts on the PCB from being connected as the schematic shows.